# Storing a yaml file in aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to load a yaml file from the folder `template` which has a file called Template-PROD.yaml
Where and how can I store this yaml file so that it can be loaded in the lambda handler?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
     const templateFile = `/templates/Template-PROD`;
     const YamlBody =  yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(templateFile, 'utf8'), { schema: SCHEMA });

}
```

There is only one yaml file that needs to be stored so that the lambda can load it. If it can be stored in tmp folder, how can I do that?

Are there any helpful links/references on how it can be stored in tmp folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Maurice corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, but the easiest is probably to package your function code and the yaml file as a zip archive.

First, create a directory with your function in a python file and your template in the subdirectory so it looks something like this:

```
function-dir
├── function.py
└── templates
    └── file.yaml
```

Now you can create a zip archive of the code:

```
cd function-dir
zip -r ./deployment-package.zip .
```

Now, within the Lambda console, upload the zip file archive. When the Lambda Function executes, it will download and extract the archive, including the template.

See also [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) for reference.